# Time synchronization issues between Linux and Windows systems

Tags: linux, windows

I have a Windows 7 and two Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) computers (W1, L1 & L2) connected via WiFi - a wired connection is unfortunately not possible. The Linux computers run chrony for time synchronization, L1 is set as source on L2, that works perfectly fine. The clocks should be as close together as possible, a 50 ms offset would already start causing problems. But for the Linux systems using chrony that's no problem at all. 
Now I also have to sync the time on W1 to L1 and unfortunately there is no chrony available for Windows. So I took this script here with the L1 IP as peer: https://gist.github.com/thedom85/dbeb58627adfb3d5c3af
One-time synchronization works, but there are some flaws:

1. The by far most problematic one: The time on the Windows system drifts away from the Linux time pretty quick. The drift is roughly about 1 s per 10 minutes on average. The easy solution - just re-syncing the clocks frequently - doesn't work due to problem 2 and 3
2. On the Windows system the sync only succeeds if there is a major time offset to the time master. If It's just a few seconds no sync happens.
3. On the Windows system the sync only gets applied after running the script, then disconnecting from the WiFi and connecting again. The clock jumps at the very moment the connection is established again.

Are there any ways to solve these problems or are there better approaches? Unfortunately I can't just steer all clocks to some high accuracy internet timing servers or GPS time since at least the Windows system is never connected to the internet and the Linux systems also can't rely on their internet connection.
At first I thought problem 1 might be caused by chrony steering the L1 clock away, but deactivating chrony after the initial sync doesn't seem to have any effect on this problem.

Here are some pictures showing the problem. W1 constantly sends messages to L2 with the current L1 time, L2 adds his timestamp on arrival and the plot shows the difference between both timestamps as observed by L2.
[image]

EDIT: L1 and L2 are both battery powered - both by the very same source. Since solely the CMOS battery should be responsible for the RTC I didn't think that this might cause any problems. However it turned out that it is. Powering these computers by AC (so AC -> AC/DC converter -> computer instead of battery -> DC/DC converter -> computer) reduces the drift significantly. But it's still not good enough:
[image]

EDIT2: **Solution / Workaround**
I disabled the crappy Windows time service (w32time) and installed [a port of the Linux NTP program](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm#ntp_stable) instead.
With quite aggressive poll rate settings this works fine:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the OS versions. Unfortunately it's Windows 7. I posted it here since I found quite some stuff about time synchronization here on stackoverflow, but you're be right, it would also fit to superuser.

Comment: You say L2 is using L1 as a ntp source, why not do the same on windows? It's just a regedit to do so, you can set it to sync to any server you'd like? (I don't know if this will fix the sync issues but maybe worth a try.

Comment: The standard Windows NTP synchronisation code is obviously inadequate, but you should be able to write your own Windows NTP client which gets the time from L1 and immediately calls `SetSystemTime()` with full subsecond resolution. Since you originally posted on http://stackoverflow.com, I presume that you'll be able to handle the programming.

Comment: You said that the Windows machine is never connected to the internet but I would assume that it has local network connectivity as you're trying to use another computer as a time server. Are the two machines on the same subnet and can you ping/establish connectivity between the Windows machine and L1?

Comment: Unless these are VMs, 1 second drift per 10 minutes is really bad! You might want to look into the cause of that as well.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I use L1 as NTP source for W1, see the linked script. I just can't run a chrony client continuously since there exists no Windows version of that tool.

Comment: @AFH So you're saying that the ntp script I used doesn't do the job? Why? I used the L1 IP in that script and that synced the clocks.

Comment: @NasirRiley L1 and L2 are on the same mobile platform and W1 is connected to this platform via WiFi. All computers are in the same subnet and can communicate with each other. Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to sync the clocks initially. L1 sometimes has access to a second WiFi with internet access, but it doesn't forward this internet connection to the other computers.

Comment: @mtak You're definitely right. L1 and L2 are on the same mobile plattform and therefore 12V battery powered. I didn't expect that that should have any influence since the internal CMOS batteries should power the RTC. But I just found out that the drift is not that nasty when I power the whole system by an external AC power supply instead of the batteries. But it's still bad. See the new plot above.

Comment: @user3296542 - I think that _you_ said that it doesn't do the job, because it doesn't reset the clock until there is a significant clock drift, and that level of drift is too coarse for your requirements (point 2). That's why I said you need to write your own synchronisation code, making your own decisions about the acceptable level of drift.

Comment: @AFH ok, then I got you wrong. Yes, that would potentially be a solution, but I'm definitely not so keen on programming a Windows client I'd have to support later on. On Linux that would be a different story... So I'm still hoping for some better solution but eventually I might have to go down this road...

Comment: @user3296542 - If you were to implement [`chrony` for Windows](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/faq.html#_operating_systems) and hand it back to the development team, they might then take over future support, though this may be just as daunting. Given the comment about CygWin, you may wish to see if `chrony` will run under Linux on Windows (released at Win10-1709, but available in beta pre-1709).

Comment: I finally found a workaround, see EDIT2 above.

Comment: Separating problems and solutions is a good practice here. Your workaround can go as an answer, I mean: not a part of the question. Other users will still be able to post their answers, if any. Besides, if I wanted to vote this solution up, but not the question itself, I could. See [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)